# Editing a PhoneGap application in XCode after it's compiled

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am creating an iOS app using PhoneGap and I have a few questions about editing the app after the initial "phonegap build ios" command.

Is it best to run the 'phonegap build ios' function for each revision / test? Or is editing within the XCode environment okay?

I have opened the application in XCode and have been editing it in that environment. I am experiencing a few issues though, primarily that I have a number of different config.xml files, and they all seem to act independently. A friend of mine said to edit the top-level version, however some changes I make in that file are not reflected unless I add them as well to the /www/config.xml file. Which config.xml should I be editing?

My folder structure is as seen here: http://cardeninteractive.com/help/loaner/folder-structure.png

Additionally, even though I've added the SplashScreen plugin and set the  for AutoHideSplashScreen to false, it still hides it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok if you want edit directly to your xcode project. But remember, you can edit all the files without worries except all files inside `staging` folder. DON'T EVER update your code here because once you run `phonegap build ios` again, all your files in `staging` folder included `config.xml` file will sync with `www` folder that you saw in `parent` folder.

[image: parent folder]

If you want to edit your files inside `staging` folder, edit inside `www` folder in `parent` folder.

Comment: So in XCode I don't touch the Staging folder? Because when I change stuff in my index.html in the Staging folder things I code in there show up on my simulation, but when I change things in the index.html folder in folder 'www' nothing appears to change from the sample project.